# What is the Difference between svn and git

Tags: linux, svn, git

What are the pros and cons of git and svn. We are suppose to use a subversion systems. Any body have a idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two points of view: http://thinkvitamin.com/code/why-you-should-switch-from-subversion-to-git/ ; http://www.findbestopensource.com/article-detail/git-vs-subversion - Google `git versus subversion` for more. Read some. Make the decision you think is best for your environment.

Answer (score 2):

Subversion is, in essence, a "better CVS": a centralised client/server version control system.

Git is a "stupid content tracker" that has build a fairly popular distributed version control system on top of it.

http://whygitisbetterthanx.com/ should help answer some of the questions about what is seen as better in Git.

Comment: It reads as if you're saying Git was built on top of svn...

Comment: Really?  If you have a suggestion about what to change to avoid that unintended implication, let me know?